# Angular 4 - Component not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Hi I am working on Angular 4. I have some functionalities (say *functionality1, functionality2, ..., functionalityN*) which is implemented in corresponding components(say *component1, component2, ..., componentN*). In my app I implemented notifications on the header. If some updations are occured, those are updated on notification, as usual. I provide routing to corresponding component as well.

Some of my components have individual view (i.e.,say component2 is not there, but **component2/user1** , **component2/user2, ..., component2/userN**). I can access  components from the notification list, but the issue I am facing is that, once I reach component2/user1 then nothing happens when try to access component2/user2, component2/user3, ... component2/userN. But I can access component2, component3, ..., componentN from component2/user1, component2/user2, ..., component2/userN.

What I understood is that issue is because component2/user1 , component2/user2, ..., component2/userN are just the views of single component component2. But there exists component2/user1 , component2/user2, ..., component2/userN and they are accessible from component1, component3, component4, ... componentN.

To access id based view of same component, from that component itself what should I do?

Hope some one can help

Comment: Need to see code

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id'];
 this.initialize(this.id);
    });
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by placing 
`this.initialize(this.id);` 
inside the subscibe method. The change is only visible there